# Is there any task that will run before azure build pipeline starts executing

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

is there any tasks that will run software installation in Azure agent before build pipeline starts running

Comment: Can you provide context for this question?

Comment: You could run your task in a docker container, and specify what you want installed there instead.

Comment: You could also take a look at Pipeline Decorators (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-pipeline-decorator?view=azure-devops) - they don't run _before_ the pipeline technically starts but they can be configured to run tasks before the rest of the job starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any tasks that will run software installation in Azure agent before build pipeline starts running

Obviously this is impossible. Before the pipeline build runs, the Azure agent is not assigned, then the task will not know where to run, and it loses the carrier to execute the task. In addition, before the pipeline build runs, the wrench that executes the task will also be lost. So this is impossible.

If you want run software installation in Azure agent before build pipeline starts running, you could create your private agent, then you could install software installation in the agent manually. So, we could achieve your request:

[Self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install)

Besides, If you just want to install the software before running some specific tasks, then you can add the task of installing the software before your specific task.